# How to reset a workbench part (one view alone) in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to reset a particular Eclipse view that I have developed. I want to reset the state of the view when I restart the application. Is there any way to achieve this in RCP programming?

Comment: I want something like how we reset the whole perspective with  page.resetPerspective().

Comment: Is this a view you have written?

Comment: Use IWorkbenchPage.resetPerspective when you restart

Answer (score 0):

When you restart your RCP application, the Eclipse workbench automatically calls the `init` method of the view parts. This method (which is located in the class `org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart`) receives a `Memento` object. This is because Eclipse, where possible, tries to recreate the previous states of the view parts. If you want to change this default behavior, override the `init` method. You can do this because your classes inherit from `org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart`.